# What gameplay effects change in multiplayer?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I know loot is allegedly better in co-op play and enemies are tougher. But I've noticed certain other things change gameplay-wise. Most noticeably, in co-op play I can Phaselock an Ion Loader through their sphere shield; in single player Phaselock doesn't affect Loaders behind the shield.

Are there other changes to gameplay mechanics beyond the simple things like money/ammo/xp/eridium sharing and difficulty?

Comment: Related question: [How does enemy difficulty scale up relative to the number of players in co-op?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86598/4797)

Comment: I've had a similar experience with the mechromancer. While playing multiplayer, the discord skill seems to activate on it's own. I've even relocated the reload button just in case I was accidentally hitting it, and the problem persisted. This has not happened once when playing single-player, and it is extremely frustrating as it makes it very difficult to accumulate a significant amount of anarchy stacks. Does anyone know whether this is supposed to happen, or is it probably just a bug in the current version?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't noticed that change - phaselock can pull an enemy (including the ION loader) from behind the shield if you target an enemy just outside it, but it still can't target the enemy inside it.

With each additional player:

- [Enemies become tougher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86598/how-does-enemy-difficulty-scale-up-relative-to-the-number-of-players-in-co-op).
- Rare (purple, fuschia and orange) loot drops become more likely.

The following items become communal - one gets it you all do:

- XP
- Money drops
- Ammo (you can now pick up ammo that you've maxed out on)
- Eridium
- Seraph crystals

Loot drops go to whoever picks them up first, as does quest related loot.

Also several items have effects dependent on the number of players equipping them, and many abilities are communal.

Comment: Try it; Phaselock can definitely hit the ion loader *producing* the shield in multiplayer, stopping the shield itself, at least it does on PC.

Comment: As a primarily Axton player, I've only ever seen phaselock in a multiplayer game.  I love it when my Maya friend stops the shield by picking up the loader in the middle.  News to me that it doesn't work in singleplayer.