# Loot quality between single player and co-op

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Multiplayer improve loot or just increase the amount of enemies and loot drops from them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86295/does-multiplayer-improve-loot-or-just-increase-the-amount-of-enemies-and-loot-dr)

Now when it's said that loot quality is better when playing co-op, does that mean the best guns will *only* be found in co-op?

It really comes down to two things.

1. Is loot equal in quality between the two but harder to find the best stuff solo?
2. Are guns dropped in co-op actually better than single because of the increased difficulty?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure it just makes enemies drop more things, paid. Haven't noticed much else